# Getting parameter value from Request.Headers.Referrer

Tags: c#, vb.net, http-headers

I have a web method (`post`) and I'm trying to get `userId` value from the the `Request.Headers.Referrer` after a user called the web service.

When debugging:

```
?Request.Headers.Referrer.ToString

"http://localhost/Omni/Activity-Feed/userId/55"
```

When I debug the value for the `OriginalString` is

```
  ?HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Headers.Referrer.OriginalString)
{http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fOmni%2fActivity-Feed%2fuserId%2f55}
    System.Web.HttpValueCollection: {http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fOmni%2fActivity-Feed%2fuserId%2f55}
```

When I am trying to get the value of userId like below, I get an empty string:

```
?HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Headers.Referrer.Query).Item("userId")
nothing

?HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Headers.Referrer.Query).Get("userId")

Nothing
```

The segments are:

```
?Request.Headers.Referrer.Segments.ToList

Count = 5
    (0): "/"
    (1): "Omni/"
    (2): "Activity-Feed/"
    (3): "userId/"
    (4): "55"
```

Any ideas how I would get the userId `value` from the referrer in the .NET way?

Answer (score 0):

Your question refers to HttpUtility.ParseQueryString().  It is not valid for what you are trying to do.  To use this function, your URL would need look like this:
"http://localhost/Omni/Activity-Feed/userId/55?userId=55"
to get the user ID.

Given the URL that you presented, this will work:

```
string segment = Request.Headers.Referrer.Segments[Request.Headers.Referrer.Segments.Length-1];
```

If necessary, find the UserId position then get the number in the next position:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> urlSegments = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>(Request.Headers.Referrer.Segments);
int i =  urlSegments.IndexOf("UserID");
string userID = urlSegments[i + 1].ToString();
```

Comment: Please note this means if the userid is in a different order your code will fail.

Comment: also, I'm getting the info from the headers.referrer

Comment: if you are programming a web method, isn't the order always going to be the same?

Comment: but this is the url which might change at any time if more parameters are added.

Comment: I think you should define what you are expecting for input a little more in the question.  To answer the variability of more parameters, then is segment position 5 always the ID number?  fi so, then grab segment 5 every time.  If it is always after userID, find the position of it in the string array 'Request.Headers.Referrer.Segments["userId"]'

Comment: and get the next one after it.

Comment: Please mark correct if this answers your question or ask for more details.  Thanks.

Comment: as I have already mentioned your example is based on fixed results which is not good in programming.

Comment: I am not understanding then.  is the 55 not always going to follow the used ID? "userId/55".  if not how will you ever identify where it is in the string?  What additional parameters may be in the URL?